# plot dataframe based on column index/position in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a dataframe based on the column index (position).
It's easy to use column name, and it shows correct plot, but since there's **duplicated** column names, I have to use column index.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
# gca stands for 'get current axis'
ax = plt.gca()

#class_report.plot(kind='line',x='description',y= "f1-score",ax=ax) #no error but shows duplicate lines
class_report.plot(kind='line',x='description',y= class_report.iloc[:,[3]],ax=ax) #error
class_report.plot(kind='line',x='description',y= class_report.iloc[:,[7]], color='red', ax=ax)#error

plt.show()
```

and it shows this error :

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

after using `np.array(class_report.iloc[:,[3]])`, new error appeared:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([ (0.6884596334819217,), (0.16236162361623618,),  (0.6314769975786926,),\n                     (0.625,),  (0.7875912408759124,),  (0.4711779448621553,),\n         (0.593069306930693,), (0.18989898989898987,),  (0.5726240286909743,),\n       (0.12307692307692307,), (0.03592814371257485,),  (0.5991130820399113,),\n        (0.4436968029750066,),  (0.5754453990621118,),  (0.5679548536332456,)],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Here's data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two columns with an identical name, you can't use the notion of

```
my_dataframe.plot(y = some_column_name)
```

Instead, use the plotly `plot` function, as in:

```
class_report = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(10), np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)), 
                            columns=["description", "f1_score", "f1_score"])

plt.plot(class_report.description, class_report.iloc[:,1])
plt.plot(class_report.description, class_report.iloc[:,2], color = "red")

plt.show()
```

I'm using random data in this example, with two columns named 'f1_score'.

The output is:

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks, may I know how can I add custom label for each line? I used `label="f1_1" ` but didn't show anything. Edit: I found the solution, have to add `plt.legend()` as well

Comment: Great. I was just about to add 'plt.legend()' to my code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the columns using

```
class_report.columns = ['description','f1-score','f1-score-2',...]  
plt.plot(class_report['description'], class_report['f1-score']) 
plt.plot(class_report['description'], class_report['f1-score-2'], color='red)
plt.show()
```

Comment: there's more than 20 columns, and the number of columns may change, so I rather not to rename the column names, but thanks :)